# Explanation: Get previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-hooks, state

I'm reading the React Documentation and there is a topic that I didn't understand very well:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const prevCountRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    prevCountRef.current = count;
  });
  const prevCount = prevCountRef.current;

  return <h1>Now: {count}, before: {prevCount}</h1>;
}
```

Demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/get-previous-state-ref--hook-faq-w0f3k?file=/src/App.js

I'd like a better explanation about this. Kind, how it's works?. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's three pieces here. A *state*, a *ref*, and an *effect*.

A state is a value that is remembered between renders, and it re-renders it's component when changed.

A reference (or *ref*) is a value that persists between renders like state does, but unlike state it's not watched for any changes and can be mutated freely. Changes to refs never cause renders.

An effect is simply a function that runs after a render, or after a render in one of its dependencies has changed since the previous render.

---

So putting that together here's what happens:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

Here a state is declared. Calling `setCount` with a new value will cause the component to render, and when it does, `count` will have the value that was set.

```
const prevCountRef = useRef();
```

Then declare the ref. This will hold a *reference* to the previous count value. Right now it no value (`undefined`), which makes sense considering there is no previous value when the component first renders.

```
useEffect(() => {
  prevCountRef.current = count;
});
```

Now declare an *effect* which runs *after* every render (you can tell this because it has no dependencies (would be the second argument to `useEffect()`). When that runs it sets the current value of `prevCountRef` to whatever the count is.

---

So, on the first render, in pseudo code:

```
// render starts

count // 0
prevCountRef.current // undefined

// render finishes

effect runs {
  prevCountRef.current is set to 0
}
```

So when the render is happening the `count` state is `0` and the previous count ref is `undefined`.

---

Second render:

```
setCount(1) // triggers the second render

// second render starts

count // 1
prevCount.current // 0

// second render finishes

effect runs {
  prevCount.current is set to 1  
}
```

---

So as you can see, during the render you always have the current count as as state, and the previous count as the ref. This works because the effect that sets the refs value always runs *after* the render is done, which allows it to be whatever the previous value was.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex. There is a phrase that I forgot. "useEffect always runs after the render" . This phrase is what I was looking for..

Thankss

Answer (score 1):

You can use componentDidUpdate to get the prev props and state.  When you extend React.Component, it will call componentDidUpdate after each render.  You define the function, and React will pass the prev props and prev state to you.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Hi @djones. I did read the part of doc.
But, in my link of documentation about about hook faqs. I did'nt understant how `prevCountRef` get the previous state with useRef. I just need a explanation.
This ain't a use case.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` is for class components and is not part of the functional component API. So this doesn't really apply here.

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` is called just after the component render.
The first time the component render prevCount is `undefined` because useEffect  has not been called yet.

pre-render:
`1) value: 0, prevCount: undefined`

post-render:
useEffect is called:

`2) value: 0, prevCount: 0` `useRef` don't cause a new rendering, thus the component is not updated. refCount will be shown as undefined.

when you change the count value the component gets re-render:

pre-render:

`3) value: 1, prevCount: 0` useEffect is not called yet.

post-render:

`4) value: 1, prevCount: 1` useEffect is called, prevCount increased but the component is not updated so prevCount will be shown the the value = 0;

Comment: Thanks @antonio! Excellently summarized explanation!